# Directory command line argument

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm having trouble taking in a path where to run the script as a command line argument, test is it exists, then changing to that path to perform work. Here what I'm trying:

```
#!/bin/bash

scriptpath=$1

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
    echo "Usage: script.sh <directory_name>"
fi

if [ -d scriptpath ]
then
    # work......
else 
    echo "Directory does not exist"

fi
```

Comment: Even if the directory exists flow falls to the else statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
if [ -d scriptpath ]
```

to this:

```
if [ -d $scriptpath ]
```

Also, I recommend making use of `""`, so that your script still behaves properly when the argument contains weird characters. (Unix allows spaces, newlines, asterisks, even control characters inside filenames.) So:

```
scriptpath="$1"

...

if [ -d "$scriptpath" ]
```